# Check out if a triangle is obtuse triangle

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, point

Let's say i have 3 points A, B, C which have coordinates A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2), C(x3, y3). What is the best way to check if the triangle is a obtuse triangle (with a angle bigger than 90 degree).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you having issues with the trig formula itself, or relating that formula to Java?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is, as it stands, purely a [math.se] question, as opposed to a specific programming problem.

Comment: I know how to calculate a angle between 3 points but i need a algorithm for this problem. I have idea but i don't know if it is the good one. For example i can calculate one angle a. if a > 90 so the triangle is obtuse. if not calculate angle b if b > 90 so the triangle is obtuse. else i have (a + b) if this sum > 90 then the triangle is not obtuse other the triangle is obtuse. But as i said i don't know if there was a better way.

Comment: You don't need the angle. You just need to know if it's > 90 deg. The sign of the dot product is enough. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more of a math question than a java question since the answer is pretty language independent. You will need to take the [dot product](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-dot-product.html) of every pair of sides.

```
double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
...
double dotAB = (x1 - x3) * (x2 - x3) + (y1 - y3) * (y2 - y3); // (A - C) * (B - C)
double dotBC = ... // ditto for (B - A) * (C - A)
double dotAC = ... // ditto for (A - B) * (C - B)
if(dotAB * dotBC * dotAC < 0){ OR if(dotAB < 0 || dotBC < 0 || dotAC < 0){
    // do obtuse processing
}
```

If any of the dot products turn out negative, you have an obtuse triangle. Since a triangle can only have one obtuse angle, multiplying the three together will tell you if one of them is negative as well.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way of doing this is,
Given the 3 coordinates,
find out the lengths of the 3 sides (X,Y,Z)of the triangle by the standard formula

```
length=√((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
```

Now provided the triangle exists,
take the 2 shortest sides.
Let us assume they are `X and Y`.
Now if

```
Z^2 > (X^2+ Y^2)
```

then the triangle is obtuse.

(The could be proved from the fact that for a right triangle, `Z^2=(X^2 + Y^2)`)

Comment: P.S. Somebody help me make these formulas more readable.

Comment: Clever. Finding out which sides are shortest will still involve as much work as taking a dot product. And you do not need a square root since it is a monotonically increasing function.

Answer (score 2):

as  Abhishek Bansal says, its a question for math.stackexchange.com.

Anyway, I show you the maths process with 3 points, you should implement it as code:

```
A=(2,-3,4), B=(0,1,2), C=(-1,2,0)
vector AB = B-A = (0,1,2) - (2,-3,4) = (-2,4,-2)
vector AC = C-A = (-1,2,0) - (2,-3,4) = (-3,5,-4)
vector CB = B-C = (0,1,2) - (-1,2,0) = (1,-1,2)


AB.AC = ||AB||.||AC || cos α
(-2,4,-2).(-3,5,-4) = √(-2)²+(4)²+(-2)² . √(-3)²+(5)²+(-4)² .cos α
(-2)(-3)+(4)(5)+(-2)(-4) = √(24).√(50) .cos α
18 = 10√30 cos α 
cos α = 18/10√30
```

"α" it is possitive between  vectors so AB y AC es agudo

Do the same for other cases:

```
AB.CB = ||AB||.||CB || cosβ 
AC.CB = ||AC||.|CB|| cosγ
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can solve this with below steps :-

1. Calculate the three sides of triangle i.e dist(A,B) using co-ordinate geometry distance between two points formula.   This will give the three sides of triangle
2. Take the two short sides of the given triangle and use them to calculate the hypotenuse of a right triangle.
3. Compare the hypotenuse to the longest side given in the problem. If the longest given side is shorter than the hypotenuse, the given triangle is acute. If it is longer than the hypotenuse, the given triangle is obtuse.